# "question feed" link shows up in print layout

Tags: bug, status-completed

If you view the print preview for a question, you'll see that the "question feed" link gets put into the print layout. A rule should be added to the `@media print` section of the stylesheet so that the link does not get printed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next deploy.